# Query performance issue with multiple left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, left-join

In mysql v8.x I have a table with about 7000 records in it. I'm trying to create a single query combines two subqueries of the same table.

I thought I could achieve this by left joining on the subqueries and then matching on any records that have values for these as shown in the example below (note: this effect happens when `my_table` has just just an id column).

The query seems to work quickly when the subqueries return records but not when the subqueries return empty (which I've recreated in the example below with `WHERE FALSE`). When this happens there is a situation where executing these queries on their own that each take a millisecond or so, takes 12 seconds.

My understanding is that these these joins should return the same number of rows as the source table and as such there shouldn't be such a big difference. I'm interested in understanding how the join works in this type of case and why it's producing such a difference in execution time.

```
SELECT my_table.* FROM accessory_requests 
  LEFT JOIN 
     ( SELECT my_table.id 
         FROM my_table  
        WHERE FALSE
     ) as join1
    ON join1.id = my_table.id 
  LEFT JOIN 
     ( SELECT my_table.id 
         FROM my_table
        WHERE FALSE 
     ) as join2
    ON join2.id = my_table.id 
 WHERE join1.id IS NOT NULL OR join2.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I never saw a MySQL version starting with 5.8.  Also, your query is syntactically incorrect, because `my_table` is not defined. And your two joins are the same so they seem redundant.

Comment: You do not really need derived tables for this, just move the inner queries' where condition into the join condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad. mysql should have read 8.x and I forgot to add some context explaining why I was setting `WHERE FALSE` in the subqueries. my_table is just an example I assume it would happen on any table as the query it's just using ids.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry This is a minimal example of the problem as far as I understand (the real  subqueries in production contain joins etc. but the issue happens without them) I'm trying to narrow down where my lack of understanding of the joins specifically. Is there something else I'm missing that could affect the performance here?

Comment: This seems like an xy problem. "What's wrong with my understanding?" is never an easy question to answer. Far easier to answer is "How do I do this?", and then allow the student to make the imaginative leap from their current (mis-)understanding to the correct position.

Comment: @Strawberry fair enough thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Your query is all messed up and it is not really clear what you are trying to do.

However, I can comment on your performance issues.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  That means that a new copy of the table is created.  In doing so, indexes are lost on the table.  So, eliminate the subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

If you ask another question with sample data, desired results, and a decent explanation, then it might be possible to help with a more efficient form of the query.  I suspect you just want `not exists`, but that is a rather large leap from this question.

Comment: I'm trying to narrow down where my lack of understanding of the joins specifically which is why I used an example that performs like this with no columns except for the id. I was under the impression that filtering on id should not need indexes as the primary key is always indexed?

Comment: @Willbill . . . The `join`s can't use indexes, if the results are materialized into a derived table.

Comment: I thought primary keys were a special case, different to normal indexes due to the fact that you don't have to define indexes for id columns by default. 

If I'm understanding you correctly, materialised tables have no indexes whatsoever and filtering on the primary key of these tables will behave as if it were an unindexed column. Thanks for clarifying. 

I must admit I'm still confused about how this same query works so much faster when the subqueries return records as those records must be joined to the base table and I'd expect performance to be worse in this case.

Comment: @Willbill . . . Your understanding is correct, in databases with poor optimizers, such as MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

> combines two subqueries of the same table.

What do you mean?

If you want to take the rows from each subquery, then simply do

```
( SELECT ... )  -- what you are calling the first subquery
UNION 
( SELECT ... )  -- 2nd
```

Also,

```
LEFT JOIN  ( ... ) as join1  ON ...
 WHERE join1.id IS NOT NULL;
```

is probably the same as simply

```
JOIN  ( ... ) as join1  ON ...
```

If by "combining" you mean to have multiple columns, then see the tag `[pivot-table]`.

Comment: Thanks. Union looks like the correct way to achieve what I was going for. I was just curious about why those left joins are so slow in only the empty case. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here but I don't think an inner join would work in this case because it would only return records that match both conditions instead of either.

Comment: Get `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see what is going on.  It might help get the desired insight.